How to add action properties to alert with azure CLI
I am attempting to bulk update a bunch of alerts using azure CLI with a couple of properties.
I can update the action group using this command :
az resource update --name AlertName --resource-group MyResourceGroup --resource-type microsoft.insights/metricAlerts --add properties.actions "actionGroupId=/subscriptions/9999/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup /providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/MyActionGroup"

I also want to add the webHookProperties in the action, but I cant seem to get the syntax correct. I get an error like :
az : ERROR: (BadRequest) Error converting value "{'test'='data'}, actionGroupId=/subscriptions/asd/resourcegroups/MyResourceGroup /providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/MyActionGroup" to type 
'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]'. Path '[1].webHookProperties'

How do I pass in the Dictionary that the command is expecting?
Thanks!

Do you want to add the webHookProperties in action for all alerts? Check this link for same thread for updating webHookProperties in action.

I am trying to update alerts that are not Metric alerts, which is why I am using the az resource update.


How to add action properties to alert with azure CLI

To update the webHookProperties  correctly in alerts, you need to format the properties.actions parameter appropriately.
Here is the updated command to add action properties to alert with azure CLI.
az resource update --name "Venkat-alert" --resource-group "Venkat" --resource-type microsoft.insights/metricAlerts --set properties.actions='[{"actionGroupId":"/subscriptions/158b8345-c359-4d98-95c5-f21815dd048f/resourceGroups/Venkat/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/Application Insights Smart Detection", "webHookProperties":{"test":"data"}}]'

Output:

After running the above command, both the Action Group ID and the webHookProperties are updated using az resource update.

Updated Answer:

Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: String. Path 'properties.actions

The above error will occur if you use --add instead of --set in the command: az resource update.


If there are actions and I am adding a new one, with your script I get the error : ERROR: (BadRequest) Error converting value "[{MyAction}]" to type 'AlertRP.Models.MetricAlerts.v20180301.MetricAlertRuleAction'

The update command will only overwrite the existing value; it won't add a new value to the existing one. Refer to the MS Doc for more details.

I updated the Action Group ID and webHookProperties in an already existing alert.

Result:

Here is the cmd to update alert type: Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules, You can check the MS DOC
az monitor scheduled-query update --name 'Demo-Alert' --resource-group 'Venkat' --action-groups "/subscriptions/123456-c359-4d98-95c5-f21815dd048f/resourceGroups/Venkat/providers/microsoft.insights/actiongroups/Venkat-Test"

Output:


I get an error with this : Error reading JArray from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an array: String. Path 'properties.actions'.
Also, I am trying to update metrics with type Microsoft.Insights/scheduledQueryRules, which this command also fails with.

The above error is when there are no current actions on the alert. If there are actions and I am adding a new one, with your script I get the error : ERROR: (BadRequest) Error converting value
"[{MyAction}]" to type
'AlertRP.Models.MetricAlerts.v20180301.MetricAlertRuleAction'

If I try to update an action when there are no actions configured, it's working fine for me. I've attached the output results for your reference. Could you please share a screenshot of the error message you're encountering with the command for further information?

Hi @evolmonster, I have updated answer, Please check and confirm.
